# Does this zero initialize the data item?

Tags: c++, initialization

I find myself confused over the rules for zero initialization in c++. With this code is data_ initialized to zero? I believe it should be, and looking at the generated assembly code with my compiler it is, but I know that's no guarentee it's required.

```
#include <iostream>

class test
{
public:
    test(); 
    int data_;
};


// Does this zero initialize data_ ?
test::test() : data_()
{
}

int main()
{
    test t;
    std:: cout << t.data_;
}
```

Comment: Yes, it does zero initialize it.

Comment: I dunno - but it is so difficult to press that extra key just to make sure.

Comment: @EdHeal it isn't a matter of pressing a key, it involves reading through the standard.

Comment: ^both are right.. yes, the standard says it will default initialize, which is 0, but on the other hand: avoid confusion for yourself and others by just writing that 0. It is clearer.

Comment: AS I said, it does initialize it for sure when I tried it, but it's hard to interpret the standard sometimes with its talk of zero initialization, default initalization etc...

Comment: Yes I wouldn't write that code as it stands of course, I'd be explicit, just trying to understand a small gap in my c++ knowledge that came up while looking at something else.

Comment: @EdHeal, what if the keyboard is italian (so `(` and `)` are 8 and 9) and the keyboard's `0` and key-pad `0` are broken? Most certainly, you shouldn't be hindered by that!

Comment: Trust me, it does, I just don't have the time to look up the relevant section of the standard right now.

Comment: @Shahbaz then you must by another keyboard

Comment: @juanchopanza - Might as well be explicit. Then there is no confusion at a later date. A casual reader does not need to scratch head etc (or dig out standard) to figure out it.

Comment: @EdHeal I agree completely, I misunderstood your first comment.

Comment: @stijn, [blasphemy!](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sarcasm).

Comment: @Shahbaz - If you are Italian then this is not a problem. They do have zero. If not change the keyboard or get to grips with that keyboard. I did that when living in France and Germany (and in some cases the company had all three (English, German and French!).

Comment: @EdHeal, I am not Italian, but "stuck" there. Since I use the US layout, if I look at the keyboard, I can't type a single punctuation! ;)

Comment: @Shahbaz - Why not get a US keyboard - Guess about 20 bucks or so. Might be a good investment. Also get a wireless one. Saves on the hassle. Just cart it from PC to PC and just plug in a dongle at the front of the PC.

Comment: @stijn: **wrong** the standard is quite explicit in that this is *value-initialization* which is different than *default-initialization*. Default initialization of a POD is actually the lack of initialization.

Comment: @EdHeal, I rarely look at the keyboard, so it doesn't make much difference. Anyway, let's not get chatty here.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes: `data_()` denotes *value initialization*, and for fundamental types, value initialization is zero initialization, i.e. `data_` will start out with value `0`.